# Is it possible to import scene module in python, but not Pythonista?

Tags: python

Regarding the subject, is it possible to import scene module in python, but not Pythonista?

Comment: Which "scene" do you mean, the sub-module of Blender? I do not find any module named "scene" [at Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=scene&submit=search).

Comment: No, it's a module in Pythonista. Here is the code sample.

Comment: from scene import *

class MyScene (Scene):
    def setup(self):
        self.background_color = 'black'

run(MyScene())

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonista `scene` module is specifically for Pythonista.  The underlying module is written in Objective C, and compiled into the app itself.  There is no way to run this outside of the Pythonista environment.

A few people have attempted to write wrappers for `pygame` that mimic the scene api.  See

https://github.com/JadedTuna/pcista

This is more geared toward the "old" `scene` module, which used simple drawing rather than the newer style SpriteNode/ShapeNode/etc approach.

Answer (score 1):

Scene was coded in *objective-c* specifically for pythonista which means that it doesn't exist outside of the app. Instead most people use *pygame* for graphics. ([You can find it here](https://www.pygame.org))